ImportError When Running PyTest with Testbook and import_ipynb in a Dockerized Python Environment
I've been working on a project that requires executing Jupyter notebooks as part of a test suite within a Docker container. The project structure involves importing Python code from one notebook to another using the import_ipynb module. While the imports work seamlessly when running notebooks individually, I encounter an ImportError when executing the test suite via pytest.
Environment:

Docker Base Image: python:3.10.8-slim-buster
Python Version: 3.10.8
PyTest Version: 8.1.1
OS: Linux (within Docker)

Error:
The error occurs when trying to import a module (calculator_nb) from one Jupyter notebook to another within pytest:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calculator_nb'

This error is triggered during the pytest execution, specifically when importing the calculator_nb module in the advanced_calculator.ipynb notebook.
Dockerfile Configuration:
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.10.8-slim-buster

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Create the env directory
RUN mkdir env

# Copy the requirements.txt file into the container at /usr/src/app/env
COPY ./env/requirements.txt ./env/

# Install system dependencies required for building certain Python packages like psutil
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gcc \
    libc-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Upgrade pip, setuptools, and wheel
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r ./env/requirements.txt

# Install code-server (Visual Studio Code in the browser)
RUN curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh

# Expose ports for Jupyter Notebook and code-server
EXPOSE 8889 8080

# Start code-server and Jupyter Notebook
CMD ["sh", "-c", "code-server --bind-addr 0.0.0.0:8080 & jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8889 --allow-root --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''"]

Pytest Code:
from testbook import testbook

# Define a list of tuples for parameterized tests. Each tuple contains inputs and the expected result.
# Example: (initial_value, operation, operation_value, expected_result)
test_data = [
    (10, 'add', 5, 15),
    # (3, 'multiply', 4, 12),
    # (20, 'divide', 4, 5),
    # (2, 'exponentiate', 3, 8),
    # (100, 'reset', None, 0)  # For reset, operation value is None
]

# Using pytest.mark.parametrize to create parameterized tests
@pytest.mark.parametrize("initial,operation,op_value,expected", test_data)
@testbook('notebooks/advanced_calculator.ipynb', execute=True)
def test_operations(tb, initial, operation, op_value, expected):
    # Import the AdvancedCalculator class from the notebook
    AdvancedCalculator = tb.ref("AdvancedCalculator")

    # Instantiate the AdvancedCalculator with the initial value
    calc = AdvancedCalculator(initial)

    # Perform the specified operation
    if operation != 'reset':
        getattr(calc, operation)(op_value)  # Dynamically call the operation method
    else:
        calc.reset()  # Special case for reset

    # Assert the expected result
    assert calc.val == expected


Notebook Import from AdvanceCalculator:
import import_ipynb
from calculator_nb import Calculator

AdvanceCalculator in notebook:
class AdvancedCalculator(Calculator):
    def multiply(self, b):
        try:
            self.val *= b
        except TypeError:
            raise ValueError("Invalid input: multiplication expects a number.")

    def divide(self, b):
        if b == 0:
            raise ValueError("Division by zero is not allowed.")
        try:
            self.val /= b
        except TypeError:
            raise ValueError("Invalid input: division expects a number.")

    def exponentiate(self, b):
        try:
            self.val **= b
        except TypeError:
            raise ValueError("Invalid input: exponentiation expects a number.")

    def reset(self):
        self.val = 0

Calculator in Notebook:
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.val = a

    def add(self,b):
        self.val += b
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Calculator instance with value = {self.val}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Calculator({self.val})"
        

I've attempted running pytest in various ways, including adjusting the PYTHONPATH, as recommended by this answer:
PYTHONPATH=`pwd` py.test tests/my_module_test.py

The project's structure and the Dockerfile have been set up as per best practices to my knowledge, yet this import issue persists exclusively in the pytest environment.
Question:
How can I resolve the ModuleNotFoundError when using import_ipynb in conjunction with testbook, and pytest? (I used the Docker Environment to isolate the issue, thus it is not a must.) Has anyone faced a similar issue, or could you provide insights into what might be missing or misconfigured in my setup?
Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
